# Display Custom Post Type within a page template in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am using [custom post type plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/types/) to create custom post types for my Wordpress website.

I want to add the custom post types to a page template. but, when I add the php loop to call the custom post type that I created, it calls the page content instead.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: please post the code you tried

Comment: This is the code I've used: http://codepen.io/umarhmz/pen/doncv

Answer (score 0):

Try this before the loop:

```
<?php query_posts(array('post_type' => 'your-cpt-name') ); ?>
```